# Heavy test for evolutionary algorithm

Tags: optimization, machine-learning

I'm trying to implement parallel evolutionary algorithm and I want to test it's performance. The best case is a heavy fitting function. What function should I choose for this test?

I've looked at multidimensional [Rosenbrock function](https://www.sfu.ca/~ssurjano/rosen.html). But I wonder is there any heavier (for computation) function for such tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the Keano's bump m-dimensional function:

$$
f(\mathbf{x}) = - \left(\sum_1^m cos^4(x_i)- 2\prod_i^m cos^2(x_i) \right)/\left(\prod_i^m i x_i^2\right)^{0.5}
$$

subject to

$$
0.75 - \prod_i^m x_i < 0, \\
\sum_i^m x_i - 7.5m < 0,\\
0 < x_i < 10
$$

Details can be found here:
https://mpra.ub.uni-muenchen.de/3098/1/MPRA_paper_3098.pdf